# memcpy and memory location

Tags: c, memcpy

According to below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
  int i = 10;
  void *byte = calloc(1, 20);
  int j;
  memcpy((char*)byte, &i, sizeof(int));
  memcpy((char*)&j, byte, sizeof(int));
  printf("%d\n", (int)*byte);
  printf("%d\n", j);
  free(byte);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is in the line

```
  printf("%d\n", (int)*byte);
```

How can I print the content of byte ?

Comment: Perhaps you want `*(int *)byte`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
 printf("%d\n", *(int *)byte);
```

OR

```
printf("%c\n", *(char *)byte);
```

For example, it `i = 65`, first option will print 65, second option will print `A`.

```
int main(void){
  int i = 65;
  void *byte = calloc(1, 20);
  int j;
  memcpy((char*)byte, &i, sizeof(int));
  memcpy((char*)&j, byte, sizeof(int));
  printf("%d\n", *(int *)byte);
  printf("%c\n", *(char *)byte);
  printf("%d\n", j);
  free(byte);
  return 0;
}
```

The result will be:

```
65
A
65
```

Comment: "second option will print A" is endian dependent.

Comment: Can you explain? I know just for string, it depends on the endian. Thanks

Comment: second option also assumes host uses ASCII or compatible character set

Comment: @rtx, i know, i agree with that you said. Thanks